# Angular 2 ngModel convert from string to Object

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I have a typescript entity that I want to show in a form:

```
class Data {
    constructor(public message: string, public properties: Object) {

    }
}
```

An instance of it would be

```
{
    message: "Hello",
    properties:{
        a: 2,
        b: 3    
    }
}
```

I want to show `properties` in an input component as a String `"a=2;b=3"` and parse back the user input of this field to the entity, and I already have the logic to do this.

Is there some way of read/convert/modify the entity on the form, without needing to create an extra entity with properties defined as string just to do the conversion apart?

For showing it, I know I can use pipes, but what about converting the user input back to the Object `properties`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use inputs to all changeable fields with two-way binding (even created dynamically), and assemble your string on the fly as any field changes?

For example like this:
Component .html:

```
<div>
    <label for="message">message:</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.message" id="message" (input)="computeProps()" />
    <br/>

    <label for="propertyes_a">properties.a:</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.properties.a" id="propertyes_a" (input)="computeProps()" />
    <br/>

    <label for="propertyes_a">properties.b:</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.properties.b" id="propertyes_b" (input)="computeProps()" />
    <br/>

    <span>The object's current values:</span>
    <pre>
    {{ model | json }}
  </pre>
    <span>Computed properties:</span><br/>
    <span>{{ computedProps }}</span>
</div>
```

Component .ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    model = { message: 'Hello', properties: { a: 2, b: 3 } };
    computedProps = '';

    ngOnInit() {
        this.computeProps(); // set initial value on load
    }

    computeProps() {
        this.computedProps = `a=${this.model.properties.a};b=${this.model.properties.b}`;
    }
}
```

Also you'll need to import FormsModule in the module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image: It looks like this, values changes as you type]

Comment: Thanks. I have as a precondition to use only one input for properties.